# How can we auto trim the property values in auto generated setters (using @Data )using lombok in a POJO?

Tags: java, spring-boot, pojo, lombok

I use lombok v1.18.6 in my pojo class. Also using @Builder and @Data annotations for auto generated setters/getters and Builder. I need to trim the property values when setting the values in automated way like annotation or by some means. So that explicitly I don't need to write the setter methods for each property. Is there any way to achieve this.Thanks in advance.

Expecting any automated ways to achieve the trim functionality when setting the property values.

```
                import lombok.*;

                @Data
                @Builder
                @NoArgsConstructor
                @AllArgsConstructor
                @ToString
                public class Sample {

                private String value1;
                private String value2;

                }
```

I expect the "value1" and "value2" values should be auto trimmed when setting the values.

If the incoming value of property value1 is "  ABC " then the value should be  "ABC" after trimming when setting the value implicitly (bcoz i use @Data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No; Lombok annotations only exist to remove the boilerplate code of actually writing your getters and setters.  It will not generate code which will mutate the data coming into your setter or leaving your getter.

If you want that, you're going to have to write it yourself, or sanitize the input *before* sending it to your POJO.

Comment: Thanks Makoto. Thanks for the response. Is there any other way to do so instead using lombok or similar framework available?

Comment: ...Besides either writing out the setters yourself, or sanitizing the input on the way into the POJO?  No.

Answer (score 0):

Lombok is only used to reduce boiler plate code and you are trying to trim some properties like you need to use Jackson parser..@JsonIgnoreProperties annotation etc.